# JavaScript For Loop does not return

Tags: javascript, loops, return, return-value

My problem is that a loop that is called in another for loop and should return an object does not return anything. When I set a breakpoint to the return statement the object is there but undefined in my callback function. *types* object is a global object that contains many objects as properties with the properties "title" and "id".

```
function searchObj(obj, query) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        var value = obj[key];

        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            searchObj(value, query)
        }

        if (value === query) {
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

The function is called from here:

```
function callback(data){
var logs = [];
var results = data.d.results;

for (var i = 0; results.length; i++) {
    var item = results[i];

    var action = util.searchObj(types, item.ActionId);

    var obj = {
        'Created': item.Created,
        'Text': String.format(action.title, item.Author.Title),
        'Author': item.Author
    }
    logs.push(obj);
}
console.log(logs);
}
```

Comment: In  the first `if` use return `return searchObj(value, query);`

Comment: that does not work for me, because if value === query is not true the loop breaks. And most of the time value === query is not true

Comment: @TimoJokinen, why should the loop break? there's no `break` in your code.

Comment: return does `break` the loop as far as i know. I created a fiddle. I want the searchObj function to return the object ADDMILESTONE https://jsfiddle.net/p0xcxhtw/3/

Comment: don't see anything wrong with your line of codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function searchObj(obj, query) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        var value = obj[key];

        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            var result = searchObj(value, query);
            if (result) {
                return result;
            }
        }

        if (value === query) {
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```